# Sequelize wrap column with " in where condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I have a JSONB column in DB.

I'd like to have request to DB where I can check if some value in this JSON it true or false:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ("json_column"->'data'->>'data2')::boolean = true AND id = '00000000-1111-2222-3333-456789abcdef'
LIMIT 1
```

So, my sequelize request:

```
const someVariableWithColumnName = 'data2';
Model.findOne({
  where: {
    [`$("json_column"->'data'->>'${someVariableWithColumnName}')::boolean$`]: true,
    id: someIdVariable,
  },
  order: [/* some order, doesn't matter */],
})
```

And sequelize generate bad result like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE "(json_column"."->'data'->>'data2')::boolean" = true AND id = '00000000-1111-2222-3333-456789abcdef'
LIMIT 1
```

Split my column by `.` and add `"` to every element.

Any idea how to get rid of adding `"` to the column in where condition?

Edit:
Here is my query with `sequelize.literal()`:

```
const someVariableWithColumnName = 'data2';
    Model.findOne({
      where: {
        [sequelize.literal(`$("json_column"->'data'->>'${someVariableWithColumnName}')::boolean$`)]: true,
        id: someIdVariable,
      },
      order: [/* some order, doesn't matter */],
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sequelize.literal()` to avoid spurious quotes.  IMHO, wrapping the json handling in a db function might also be helpful.

Comment: With Sequelize.literal() I got something like this: ...WHERE "[Object object]" = true AND...

Comment: Sequelize.literal requires a string, not an object.  Wish I could test this, but we are a MySql shop.  Maybe if you post exact code with literal()?

Comment: i think you should remove the square brackets [] around literal()....

Comment: I can't remove [] because it's key in object

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar use case.

I believe you can use the static `sequelize.where` method in combination with `sequelize.literal`.

Here is the corresponding documentation in sequelize API reference: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-where](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-where)
And here is an example (although I will admit hard to find) in the regular documentation:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#advanced-queries-with-functions--not-just-columns-

In the end for your specific sit try something like this:

```
const someVariableWithColumnName = 'data2';
Model.findOne({
  where: {
[Op.and]: [
  // We provide the virtual column sql as the first argument of sequelize.where with sequelize.literal.
  // We provide the matching condition as the second argument of sequelize.where, with the usual sequelize syntax.
  sequelize.where(sequelize.literal(`$("json_column"->'data'->>'${someVariableWithColumnName}')::boolean$`), { [Op.eq]: true }),
  { id: someIdVariable }
]
})
```